# ATI streams failed on AMD 7970 series

Tags: opencl, ati

I have a program (not mine - downloaded from i-net) made on ATI streams (more accurate - on brook lang - file is *.br). There is a python script (see below), that compiles it into *.il file using brook compiler, provided by ATI streams SDK. After it script zips it into *.Z file. C-program's Makefile contains this code

```
my_kernel_dp11.o: my_kernel_dp11.Z
ld -s -r -o my_kernel_dp11.o -b binary my_kernel_dp11.Z
```

and then it linked to main executed file.
Data from that obj-file read by C-program into some buffer and then called ***calclCompile*** function (as I understand it's OpenCL func).
It works fine at AMD HD 6970-series, but failed at AMD HD 7970-series with following error

> **Unsupported program construct detected in back-end**

Here is a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import zlib
import os
def makebrz(dp_bits):
try:
    os.unlink("a_slice_dpX_a_slicer.il")
except OSError:
    pass
dpdefs=""
for i in range(dp_bits-11):
    dpdefs = dpdefs + " -D DP_BIT_%i" % (i+12,)
print "DP_DEFS: ", dpdefs
os.system("/usr/local/atibrook/sdk/bin/brcc -k -pp %s a_slice_dpX.br" % (dpdefs,) )
f = open("a_slice_dpX_a_slicer.il")
if f==None:
    print "Could not read ", sys.argv[1]
    sys.exit(-1)
data = f.read()
f.close()
oname = "../my_kernel_dp%i.Z" % (dp_bits,)
data2 = zlib.compress(data)
fo = open( oname, "wb" )
fo.write(data2)
fo.close()
#os.system("ld -s -r -o ../%s.o -b binary %s" % (oname[:-2],oname))
makebrz(11)
makebrz(12)
makebrz(13)
makebrz(14)
```

And here is a program http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46469564/a_slice_dpX.br

The question is: what should I do to make it program "supported" ?
P.S. There is one problem - I don't know this technology (brook, ATI streams, OpenCL) at all. That's why advice like "you should try this or that" are useless. I need particular action to do - change this and you'll have a success :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Radeon HD7970 is built on GCN architecture, so if you are using brook to generate IL code, JIT in southern island may not know how to generate proper ISA for the h/w you are using,so if you would like continue using brook+ then you need to wait till an updated version of Brook+ gets released on sourceforge which can generate an IL which gets converted to right ISA(GCN).

Other option is to use AMD APP SDK 2.6 and rewrite your code in OpenCL.

Comment: It's sad. I saw sourceforge - the latest brook+ dated 2009th year. I can't use other option (OpenCL), because I don't know either brook, or OpenCL... Thank you nevertheless.